# RPC/Servlet not working when deployed in Tomcat as ROOT

Tags: gwt, tomcat, servlets

I have a GWT application which I have deployed in Tomcat. When I deployed it in the webapps folder like this:

```
webapps/mygwtapp
```

and accessed it from the browser, http://localhost:8080/mygwtapp the server side RPC/Servlet works.

However when I changed the `mygwtapp` folder to be `ROOT` folder the RPC/Servlet stops working.

One servlet configuration, this works when the app is not deployed as ROOT:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mygwtapp/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

However when deployed as ROOT its not working, even if I change the url-pattern this way:

```
<url-pattern>/greet</url-pattern>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please explain what specifically isn't working. Provide error messages and/or stack traces if possible.

Comment: The RPC is failing because the servlet url-pattern i think is not mapped correctly.

Comment: However when I transfer the app from ROOT to mygwtapp in the webapps folder it just works (i.e. if the url-pattern is like this: <url-pattern>/mygwtapp/greet</url-pattern>

Comment: BTW, in the client side service there is this annotation: @RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet"), could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even using ROOT it the path can still be '/mygwtapp/greet'

The pattern is **[context]** / **[project name]** / **[servlet]**, so in this case of using ROOT it is / + mygwtapp + greet

**1)** Check the path of your java script on your page, it should be...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="mygwtapp/mygwtapp.nocache.js"></script>
```

I would use a trace tool to see what result you get for the javascript,  Firefox/Firebird, Chrome/Developer Tools or IE/HttpWatch is good. You should be getting a 200, if not it this path that is the problem.

**2)** Check your folder layout in the ROOT folder, you should have the following

```
ROOT
 |->mygwtapp (your mygwtapp.nocache.js should be here)
 |->WEB-INF
```

**3)** Check you web.xml paths, which should be /mygwtapp/greet and your @RemoteServiceRelativePath should be "greet"

Hope that helps.

Comment: With this approach you suggested, when I access http://localhost:8080 it will process mygwtapp automatically? I mean like forward the request to ROOT\mygwtapp?

Comment: Does the trace for http://localhost:8080/mygwtapp/mygwtapp.nocache.js when you load the page give a result of 200?